# How to set a specific browser (Internet Explorer) to be default only for a specific application

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer, webpage, html-files

We have an enterprise software that shows reports properly only in IE, but I don't want to set IE as my default browser.

The application is a WPF/Silverlight based desktop application - not a web app, but the reports are produced in HTML in the browser. I have found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/130672/how-do-i-set-the-windows-default-browser-for-a-custom-application-like-foobar) answer, but didn't understand how the reg scripts exactly work and how should I customize it.

- Our accounting software generates an HTML report. I can't control the
  doctype, HTML template or anything else.
- The generated document (the report) opens up in a browser in a local URL:

  `file:///D:/Users/ALONIS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/p0430400234.htm`

Comment: Please add an example report and the format of its URL.

Comment: [What are you _really_ trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/171857)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve your goal, is by using the [**IE Tab**](http://www.ietab.net/) extension for your default browser (Firefox / Chrome).

Instead of trying to set a default browser for a specific application [on the Windows side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29) - which is way more complicated, do it on the browser side.

> **What Is IE Tab?**
>
> IE Tab for Chrome (and IE Tab 2 for Firefox) is a browser extension
>   that allows you to use Internet Explorer to display web pages in a
>   tab. This is useful in many cases where a web page requires Internet
>   Explorer features.
>
> **Features**
>
> Auto URLs - Allows you to specify which URLs should always be loaded
>   with IE Tab.

As you can see, the reason IE Tab is very useful in your case, is because it has the **Auto URLs** feature.

Instead of settings a specific browser for a specific application, you can simply tell IE Tab to be activated whenever you launch a certain URL.

And even better - it supports Regular Expressions, so whether your report is created as an `html` file offline (locally) or online, it will be very easy to tell IE Tab to always open your reports - which lets you view them in an IE environment - inside your default browser.

For example, if you reports are online, you can add `http://www.myonlinereports.com/*` to the Auto URLs to automatically open in IE Tab every page of the `www.myonlinereports.com` website.

If you reports are offline, you can add something like `r/file:///D:/My%20Documents/My%20Reports/.*` (don't forget the `r/` prefix) to the Auto URLs to automatically open in IE Tab every file inside the `My Reports` folder.

[image]

Comment: also not the exact solution to my problem, this goes for giving some bearable solution, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Can you give a sample of the report? What exactly doesn't work in other browsers?

On the SE network, it's often better to give the reader an idea of the big picture and what you're trying to do. My say is that it shouldn't have any major problems in today's age of standard-compliant browsers (even IE9! Can you believe that?)

If you do have problems, you can try changing the DOCTYPE to maybe something very old which will cause browsers to enter into *quirks* mode (equivalent of IE's *Compatibility Mode*).